# Proving the piecewise function specified is differentiable (Real Analysis)

Tags: real-analysis

> **Problem:** For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $g_n : (-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function. Assume that $g_n(0) = g' _n(0) = 0$ for all $n$ and suppose that there exists some $M \in \mathbb{R}$ so that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and all $x \in (-1,1)$ we have $|g_n '' (x) | \leq M$.
>
> Define 
>   $g(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> g_n(x),  & x = \frac{1}{P_n ^m} \text{ for some } m \in \mathbb{N} \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}.
> \end{cases}$
>
> Prove that $g$ is differentiable at $0$.

I am not sure about how to proceed with this problem or if my approach is correct. I believe that I should prove that for some $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|x| < \delta$ implies $|g_n ' (x)| < \epsilon$ simultaneously for all $n$. Any suggestions on how to work this problem, or if this approach is completely false? (I am using baby Rudin and reached L'Hôpital's Rule in the chapter concerning differentiability.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose $p_n$ in your definition stands for the n-th prime number. By MVT $|g'_n (x)| =|g'_n (x)-g'_n(0)| \leq M|x|$. Hence, by another application of MVT $|g_n (x)| =|g_n (x)-g_n(0)| \leq M x^{2}$.  Hence $|\frac {g(p_n^{-m}) -g(0)} {p_n^{-m}}| \leq M(p_n^{-m})^{2} / {p_n^{-m}}=M{p_n^{-m}} \leq Mp_n^{-1} \to 0$. Hence $g'(0) =0$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime number. I was wondering, I don't need to write any epsilon or deltas to be more precise in the proof you gave?

Comment: Since we don't know what exactly is the n-th prime we cannot give a precise delta for a given epsilon.